# How to properly format a text file to be read for everyone

Tags: bash

After generating some MySQL scripts I get some output tables that I arrange with awk+printf in order to get everything perfectly aligned and beautifull.
But, when sent to anyone else, if the file is opened within Windows, Blackberry or Android, it looks awkfull and misaligned.

Is there any tipe of format (apart from pdf or images) that I can be sure everyone would read properly?
Present format is:

```
$ file sample.txt 
sample.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Thanks.

Comment: nope, plain text file formats do not offer a standard way to represent a formatted layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sounds like you're using a fixed-width font (like courier) that is typical to a terminal session and relying on it to line up you data nicely. And for those instances it works fine. Also if a user defaults their mail reader to use a fixed-width font.

The problem is then you send your message to someone that uses a GUI tool (like outlook, or a web-mail client, or many others) that uses proportionally spaced characters, so an '1' takes up less space than an '0' (for example), and then you get something that is ugly.

If this is for a corporate project and the range of supported mail readers is limited, you should be able to "wrap" your report in  and specify a fixed-width font. Even in a corporate organization, this can still not be perfect AND if your user base is more general, then it gets more difficult to make sure everyone gets a perfectly formatted report. Maybe you need to add some qualifications like "best formatting presented when using xxx mail reader".

You can post to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ here and ask for advice on simple HTML formatting that has a high probability of a correct rendering.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, most universal formatted text option is HTML. Sticking to HTML 2.0 or 3.2 (for tables) will offer the fewest chances for the client to get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the tech savvy of your coworkers, but I'd suggest using a CSV since that is a relatively common format in most offices. Otherwise, yes, html tables are an excellent way to go.

Not sure what the structure of your data is, but you might be able to grok it into a comma delimted format, or use a Perl/Python script to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Tab characters (ASCII 9), your table should line up even in a proportional font.  It's not perfect, but most programs display it correctly.  To make a tab character in printf, specify it as `\t`.

Comment: Using tabs also has the advantage that spreadsheets can import them, just like csv files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you all for your comments.
My solution was:

1. I tried txt2htm to check how my original code (I mean, my data table) was being transformed.
2. I arranged a bit the code to leave it the simplest way.
3. As my txt file is already "nice", I just have to insert the following coded in the begining and the end of every txt file I have to share with others.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
   <pre>

   HERE GOES MY FIXED WIDTH TABLE

   </pre>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

The key tag here is `<pre>`, wich literally:

> "The `<pre>` tag defines preformatted text. Text in a `<pre>` element is
>   displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves
>   both spaces and line breaks."